# sencha with web service integration

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch 2 development.

My doubts are:

1. How to integrate web service in sencha touch?
2. Can anyone suggest me a good sencha touch tutorial with web service integration?
   I searched a lot but didn't get specific tutorial.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should check out sencha documentation for REST proxy and its usage

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest

For more details check out

http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/06/21/an-app-in-an-afternoon-sencha-touch-and-stackmob/